# Unable to remove extra space between CardView items - Scrollable RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Folks,

I am out of options while attempting to removing extra space between cardview items in my recyclerview below is the current output. Please suggest.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:background="#303030">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:background="@drawable/vector_red"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSub" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtMain"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtSub"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMain"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My Recycler view

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:background="#0fffffff" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240078/modify-cardview-padding ?  That one has no answer either, unfortunately.

Comment: Right but the padding is comparively ok, i get an ugly looking cardview,. need a compact view atleast.

Comment: can you post a screenshot what you want ? @xtechkid

Comment: Thereis a lot of padding you are using, just remove that!

Comment: card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" make it "false" in first xml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not implemented a `RecyclerView`, however I have replicated two rows in a linear layout, minus the padding from your original question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:id="@+id/cv1"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:background="#303030">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:background="@drawable/vector_red"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSub" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtSub"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:id="@+id/cv1"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:background="#303030">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:background="@drawable/vector_red"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSub" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtSub"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Play around with the padding and you will get better results. You can also try adding a background color to your card, then you can get rid of layout margins in your RelativeLayout!

Comment: let me check and get back

Comment: Glad that helped mate :)

Comment: i have done the same , but it gives me id's error bocz of duplications

Comment: Unless you want fixed cards (2 in this case), set android:layout_height="wrap_content" on your Card root LinearLayout

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is remove the following two lines from the xml for the `CardLayout`:

```
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
```

What this does is sets the seperation between the two layouts, in this case you have `4dip` (2 at the top and 2 at the bottom). You can also try to reduce it to `1 dip` and verify the effect it gives you.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
...
...
...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have checked, it works fine for me.

**Check screenshot:**

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

change your card layout to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#303030"
         android:id="@+id/cv"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the card view xml  change in the overall parent layout width to wrap content.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```