# Modify cardview padding

Tags: android, android-cardview

[image]

For card elevation to be visible, I use the attribute `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` in cardview XML. It added extra padding on all four sides of the cardview, but I do not need the bottom padding since the card below every card will already have a top padding. So currently it is like double padding between two cards because of top+bottom padding. How to reduce it by half?

P.S `android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Only use a margin at the bottom for the cards and set a padding to the top of your RecyclerView/ListView holding the cards:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

Comment: but ' card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" ' automatically adds margins on all four sides to the card. Without that attribute, card elevation wont work for me.

Comment: Then you have to add a negative margin to the card

Comment: As I already mentioned in the last line of my question, adding negative margin doesn't work